# Передача данных из alert

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой и надеюсь что найдутся люди, который подскажут что не так.

Не первом View Controller вызывается alert, где есть 2 кнопки, при нажатии на одну из них происходит переход на другой контроллер. Так вот хотелось бы при этом переходе передавать некоторое значение. Вот то, что я пробовал сделать:

```
            let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "События на выбранный день:", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

                optionMenu.message =  "Текст"

 let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Закрать", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

            let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Перейти к событиям", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{
                (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                let toShow = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventOfCalendar") as TableSelectEvents

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(toShow, animated: true)
        })
        optionMenu.addAction(callAction)
        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Ниже пишу функцию prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "EventOfCalendar" {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as TableSelectEvents
            destinationController.text2 = "Edik"
        println("ok2")


    }
}
```

на сколько я понимаю, программа даже и не вызывает эту функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете

```
let toShow = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventOfCalendar") as TableSelectEvents
navigationController?.pushViewController(toShow, animated: true)
```

то здесь и настраивайте UIViewController, на который осуществляете переход:

```
let toShow = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventOfCalendar") as TableSelectEvents
toShow.text2 = "Edik"
navigationController?.pushViewController(toShow, animated: true)
```

если хотите использовать **prepareForSegue** вам нужно вместо конструкции
**instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier/navigationController?.pushViewController** настроить sugue в стриборде визуально, ctrl+drag с одного UIViewController на другой, в сториборде же дать этой segue identifier = "EventOfCalendar" и тогда уже будет отрабатывать prepareForSegue.

также учтите, что тип `segue.identifier` - `String?`, то есть это **Optional**, а у вас может быть в последствии множество segue и некоторые могут и не иметь identifier и лучше этот момент обрабатывать, чтобы **избежать крэша когда identifier будет равен nil**:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        switch segue.identifier {
        case .Some("EventOfCalendar"): (segue.destinationViewController as? TableSelectEvents)?.text2 = "Edik"
        default: break
        }
    }
```

либо

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == .Some("EventOfCalendar") {
         (segue.destinationViewController as? TableSelectEvents)?.text2 = "Edik"
    }
}
```